# Selenium UnreachableBrowserException - Java

Tags: java, selenium, exception, browser, unreachable-statement

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();   
        driver.navigate().to("https://link");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#username")).sendKeys("id");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#password")).sendKeys("pass");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#clientName")).sendKeys("name");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#submitButton")).click();
        System.out.println("Okay !");
```

I set property for Chrome Driver. When I run it gives an error. (Below) I searched a lot but didn't found any solution.

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab) on port 10589
Only local connections are allowed.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T15:15:03.216Z'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-9HVORCR', ip: '192.168.1.24', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:564)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:207)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:130)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
    at zaaa.main.main(main.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected char 0x131 at 23 in User-Agent value: selenium/3.12.0 (java wındows)
    at okhttp3.Headers$Builder.checkNameAndValue(Headers.java:338)
    at okhttp3.Headers$Builder.add(Headers.java:288)
    at okhttp3.Request$Builder.addHeader(Request.java:177)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.OkHttpClient.execute(OkHttpClient.java:85)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:101)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
    ... 6 more
```

I have tried these:

1. 32/64 bit drivers.
2. Run it as administrator.
3. Creating a Try/Catch block.
4. Other drivers. (Like Operadriver.exe) (Result: Same error)

Comment: You have an illegal character in the path. Since it works well on another computer I assume its in the computer name.

Comment: I tried other chars too "\\" "/". It's not about path because IDE finds driver and runs at the beginning.

Check top of error code:
Starting ChromeDriver 2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab) on port 10589
Only local connections are allowed.

Comment: Its not about what you wrote in the code. Selenium uses the machine information, including the computer name. I'm guessing the problem is there.

Comment: I just changed it, same result. 
Starting ChromeDriver 2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab) on port 4892
Only local connections are allowed.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T15:15:03.216Z'
System info: host: 'SUPPLYCHAIN', ip: '192.168.1.24', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_171'

Comment: Your ChromeDriver Browser version? Using client jars or stand-alone jar?

Comment: I tried both. First client and then stand-alone jar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your windows is not english. I am having the same problem. When I tried the same in an english version windows 10 the code works without any problem.

Comment: `Locale.setDefault(new Locale("tr", "TR"));` should works.

Comment: this is not the answer of the question. See my answer below. I changed the cause of this problem and my pull request got accepted. It should be fine with the next release of Selenium.

Answer (score 1):

```
Locale.setDefault(new Locale("en", "EN"));
```

you can also try this. it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines before instantiating "WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();"

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
```

Then add the argument where you have declared Webdriver as shown below:-

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: I have same problem for Opera and IE too. I have 2 computers but I work with this one. Same programs and versions installed. I have tried on Netbeans and Eclipse. All drivers have same error. It could be not about the code. Code works on other computer well.

Comment: The reason in this error message is "Possible causes are an invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure". You can try updating selenium server standalone version and chrome driver version and also make sure the IP address you are using is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are using
**selenium version** : 3.12.0
**chromedriver version** : 2.40

When i tried to run with these configurations (they are latest at present)
I am able to launch the application without any exception and in the logs getting :

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab) on port 35584
Only local connections are allowed.
Jun 21, 2018 2:42:51 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Okay !
```

which is same as your starting logs. 
My chrome browser version is :

```
Version 67.0.3396.87 (Official Build) (64-bit)
```

I think you should check your .m2 folder and delete

> .m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium

folder from there and then again try to download the dependencies.

Also update to latest chrome browser version.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem of Turkish Windows. As it is indicated in exception message the 'ı' character in user agent value "selenium/3.12.0 (java wındows)" is the cause of the exception. 
The problem is the string "**WINDOWS**" is changed to lower case and it results "**wındows**" because of TR locale. I found that it is generated in class `org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpClient`and added `Locale.US` like this.

```
String USER_AGENT = String.format(
      "selenium/%s (java %s)",
      new BuildInfo().getReleaseLabel(),
      (Platform.getCurrent().family() == null ?
          Platform.getCurrent().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.US) :
          Platform.getCurrent().family().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.US)));
```

I compiled the library with my changes and it works now. I also opened a [pull request](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/6491) on github.

You can also find my edited fork [here](https://github.com/bozdemir84/selenium).

Comment: So My pull request is merged and this problem will be solved with the next release of Selenium.